# Nameservers, no delegation with parent

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, plesk

**Problem**
Trying to point nameserver to my server dns settings, returning errors.

[image: Dns Check]

[image: Dns Settings]

As far as I can see the dns records on the server are setup correctly, can anyone help me out of this mess? My business has been down for three days and I have some very unhappy customers. Next migration will be well thought out!

ps: i would add more images however, my reputation doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming polydevs.co.uk is the domain the problem you have is the following

Take a look at [Nominet](http://www.nominet.uk/whois/?query=polydevs.co.uk#whois-results) your name servers are registered as

> ns1.ipage.com
>     ns2.ipage.com

DNS lookups will not get to ns1 or ns2 .polydevs.co.uk. If you want to control your DNS through that control panel update your Name servers where you brought the domain to be `ns1.polydevs.co.uk` and `ns2.polydevs.co.uk`

Comment: the problem is I cannot change the nameservers to ns1.polydevs.co.uk or ns2.polydevs.co.uk I get an error when trying to do so.

Comment: I know the current nameservers are that.

Comment: But you haven't posted any errors? The screen shots aren't showing errors trying to set something

Comment: I thought the error could be on my end. As the dns check gave me the impression it was my issue on the server. However, the error was a registry error. I've tried again now and it has accepted them name servers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, good it is sorted